# The Nested Interval Property implies the Axiom of Completeness

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Prove that an ordered Archimedean field with the Nested Interval Property obeys the Axiom of Completeness.  *(There are many proofs of this available; my question is for verification and critique of* my *proof and its exposition.)*

First, we formalize the question: Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an ordered field such that:

(1) For any $x,y > 0\in \mathbb{F}$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y/2^n < x$.  (For clarification, $0$ is the field's additive identity, $1$ is its multiplicative identity, $2$ is $1 + 1$, and $2^n$ means $1 * 2 * 2 * 2...n$ times.)

(2) For any sequences $(a_n), (b_n)$ in $\mathbb{F}$, if $(a_n)$ is monotonically increasing, $(b_n)$ is monotically decreasing, and, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, a_n \leq b_n$, then there exists a $x \in \mathbb{F}$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, a_n \leq x \leq b_n.$

Then any non-empty set $S$ in $\mathbb{F}$ with an upper bound $B$ has a least upper bound in $\mathbb{F}$.

**Proof:** Let $s \in S$.  Since the set is non-empty, such an $s$ exists and is $\leq B$.  Construct three sequences $(a_n), (b_n), (c_n)$ as follows:

- $a_1 = s$
- $b_1 = B$
- $c_n = (a_n + b_n)/2$
- (i) If there exists $t \in S$ such that $t \geq c_n$, then $a_{n+1} = c_n$ and $b_{n+1} = b_n$.
- (ii) Otherwise, $a_{n+1} = a_n$ and $b_{n+1} = c_n$.

By induction and the ordered field axioms, $a_n \leq c_n \leq b_n$ for all $n$, and $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ meet the conditions of (2), so there exists a $x \in \mathbb{F}$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, a_n \leq x \leq b_n.$  By (1), $(a_n - b_n) \to 0,$ and thus this $x$ is unique.

$x$ is upper bound of $S$.  Suppose there exists $r > x \in S$.  Then condition (i) is always met, and $x = B$, a contradiction.

Suppose there exists an upper bound $u < x$.  Then for any $n$ such that $c_n \geq u$, condition (i) is not met, leading to a contradiction [*].  Thus, $x$ is a least upper bound of $S$.

**Questions:**

1. Is my proof correct?
2. Can you help me write out the part I marked with a "[*]"? I believe the argument robust, but am struggling to write it clearly.
3. Can the exposition be clarified? I'm surprised that the writing ended up being so long for what I expected was a simple argument.

Comment: I don't see why $r > x$ implies condition (i) is always met. Also don't write, $r > x \in S$. People will think you mean $x \in S$.